# Vue.js webpack export code for production

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, vue.js, vuetify.js

This is the first time I have used a frontend Build Tool. In the past I have never used any type of a framework that was more complicated to install than just adding a `<script>` tag to the top of my html page. Now you know my level of knowledge.

I have a vue.js/vuetify application with directory structure like this:

[image: build, build.js, config, css, index.html, node_modules, package-lock.json, package.json, README.md, src, static. src -> App.vue, assets, components, main.js, router, stylus]

I think it started with the vuetify/webpack advanced template. 
And I am trying to export the project into something that I can put online. I have in my head that somehow I can run some type of a command that will generate all my code into .html, .css, and .js files that I could then hook up to any sort of backend that I wanted.

If my assumption is correct, and that's how things are done, then how is routing handled? Is the entire site just in one html file?

I think webpack is supposed to do this maybe? However when I try to run `webpack` from the command line, `I get command not found`.

If my assumption is wrong, then how do I get this online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `npm run build` command. You can see what the command does inside the `package.json` file, scripts object.

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
 }
```

Your entire site will be compiled into the `index.html` file and the `build.js` file located in the `/dist` folder. Both the `/dist` folder and the `build.js` are generated when you run the `npm run build` command. Make sure the script `src` inside of `index.html` is pointing to your `build.js` file.